# Cognos Viewer remove "open with report studio" option

Tags: business-intelligence, cognos, viewer

We have upgraded from cognos bi 8.4 to 10.1.

Reports are ran directly view links we provide straight to the prompt page, when the report is ran Cognos Viewer opens and report is displayed in pdf...however the users have an option on the toolbar on top right side to "open with report studio", how do i disable/hide this option??

It is beside the options to view report as html and excel etc.

I can see how to remove the view report at html by editing the system.xml file... but i cannot see how to remove this option for opening in report studio.

Any help would be good!

Comment: The easiest way is to not give them access to that function. Then they won't see it. Is that an option?

Comment: The username that is used to access the reports should be able to access report studio via cognos connection...I just need to restrict Report Studio being accessed from the output page when report is ran directly.

Answer (score 0):

[IBM has an article about this.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_10.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.ug_cra.10.1.0.doc/ug_cra_id36310CustomizetheUserInterfaceBasedonGroupandR.html%23CustomizetheUserInterfaceBasedonGroupandRoleMembership)  Skip to the 'Using URL Commands' section.

In your link to the report, add '&cv.toolbar=false' to remove the toolbar that contains the Report Studio link.  You can also add '&cv.header=false' to remove the Cognos View title bar.

If removing the toolbar is an issue (you need other functions), then you can remove options using system.xml

This includes options beginning with RV_ that will remove tools from the Report Viewer.  However the 'Open in Report Studio' is not an option.

Your best bet in this case is to:

1. Remove the entire Toolbar ( RV_TOOLBAR )
2. use the  option to add back in the required elements (XML output, saveas, etc).

With the toolbar removed, this may require some tweaking to achieve a desirable web page layout.

Comment: I have seen this document, but these options remove the whole toolbar, meaning that users will not have option of viewing in excel or html if they need.

There are options to remove certain icons in the toolbar here: (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_10.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.ug_cra.10.1.0.doc/ug_cra_id53939ElementsYouCanHide.html%23ElementsYouCanHide)

But does not mention the Report Studio Option here.

Comment: I see what you are saying.  I have edited my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks, i havent got round to trying this yet... but i think it looks correct and will mark as correct when i test it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can revoke an access to Report Studio for users.
Go to Cognos Administration -> Security -> Capabilities and set up access to RS there

Comment: Read his comments above.  The users need access to report studio, but he doesnt want them to see the link in Cognos Viewer when running reports.